# MYSQL access from another computer

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I want to develop a java desktop application, in which i want to setup server, means here I am using mysql db. The db will be stored on only one pc, and rest all users can access this db. 
so, i heard about mysql remote connection.
in which tried some things,
these are as follows:

(My pc is connected to wifi)
1)i assigned a static ip to the pc

2)added inbound and outbound rules in firewall setting for port 3306

3)in my.ini file of mysql, i have added bind-address=the static ip of my pc.
(Please note here, i dont know much about this bind-address logic. i have tried 0.0.0.0, ::, * everything as a value of bind-address.but nothing worked. so in my.ini file, current value saved is the static ip of my pc.

4)user has been added with all permission along with username and password. using mysql workbench.

but,now when that user tries to access my db, on his pc, using command...

mysql -u username -p 'password' -h 'static ip of my pc' dbname;

its not working....

please someone tell me, where i am making mistake...please

Comment: what error do you get ?

Comment: can you ping the database's PC from the other computer?

Comment: Please specify what _exactly_ you mean by "not working".

Comment: No i cant ping...

Comment: The error i am geeting when i tried the java connection code is,.....com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

Comment: i also tried it using online mysql connection test tool... its saying Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.*.***' (13)

Comment: please someone, help